# Any way to restrict access to Hyper-V Administrator snap-in via GPO?

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

Windows Server 2012 R2 Domain with Windows 10 Pro clients.

I'm poking around in GPO under

`User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Microsoft Management Console -> Restricted/Permitted snap-ins`

Looks like the perfect place for it to be, but it isn't

Can I add it manually anyway?

Comment: Since Authorization Manager has been deprecated, I'm not aware of any way to implement RBAC for Hyper-V other than with SCVMM.

Comment: I'm not even looking to specify per-user roles at this point.  I'm looking for a hammer.  I'd like to just completely disable the snap-in.  That seems like it should be a terribly easy task, and yet it is not.  At this point I'm just going to try restricting access to `MMC.exe` entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit administrative template file `"C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\MMCSnapins.admx"` and see what is changed if you enable any of the settings in that GPO section. It'll show you that it's using the ID of the snap-in and the value `Restrict_Run` with a value of `1`.

1. Google for "mmc snap-in registry location"
2. Open regedit and go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MMC\Snapins
3. Install Hyper-V Management Tool and check the new snap-in's ID in this location
4. If snap-in is already installed, just browse the keys and find related snap-in and its ID

Now you know your snap-in's ID, you need to use it in GPO. There are couple of ways to do that.

You can edit the administrative template file (`"C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\MMCSnapins.admx"`) you used before and add a new policy section with Hyper-V snap-in's ID, or, you can use admx file to see what is modified in registry when you change that Group Policy setting and deploy correct settings with GP preferences.

Instead, I just changed one of the settings using gpedit.msc , opened `"C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Registry.pol"` in notepad to see what it changed, opened regedit and added the new key with snap-in's ID and value.

After testing to see if it worked, you can export it and deploy it using GP preferences.

```
SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MMC\FX:{922180d7-b74e-45f6-8c74-4b560cc100a5}
"Restrict_Run"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: Details as to how you found this GUID would be really useful for folks in the future.

Comment: Ooooh.  Ya, tell us how this works.

Comment: Thanks to your lead I found this page that seems to detail how to add it to a custom Administrative Template: https://asteriksz.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/hyper-v-management-snap-in-engedelyezese/  Seems to be in Hungarian, but Google does a decent job of auto-translate.

Comment: worked, though you have an extraneous bracket there